# Adding in datatypes from database table

Tags: c#

I have got a SQL database table in which i am querying from in my c# project. The table contains  a column that takes in int as a datatype (Employers Age). I am querying from this column and I would like each and every record that is queried from this column to be added up and display the total of the records;

Code:

```
int AddAge;
string getAge;

    Query = "SELECT * FROM TblEmp WHERE Id = '" + id + "' AND Position = '"+Manager+"'";
                       theReader = conn.ExecuteStatement(Query);
                       while(theReader.Read())
                       getAge = theReader["Age"].ToString();
                       AddAge = int.Parse(getAge);


                     AddAge + getAge; // this is where i am stuck, How can I add up the ages and display the the total?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add your code inside brackets

```
while(theReader.Read())
{
                       getAge = theReader["Age"].ToString();
                       AddAge = int.Parse(getAge);


                     AddAge + getAge;
}
```

And if you need only the sum of Ages you can change your SQL statement

```
Query = "SELECT SUM(Age) FROM TblEmp WHERE Id = '" + id + "' AND Position = '"+Manager+"'";
```

then `execute reader.executescalar`